# unable to view My UI after installed Vuex in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

working with Laravel and Vue JS. I have installed Vuex with the project. but now My all User Interface not view as before. route is working as well. not any error message also. how could I fix this problem?

Comment: The question cannot be answered in its current form. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I have installed vuex using following command as well 'npm install vuex' then after that my User Interfaces not working not loading menus and other bodies. Then what should I do fix this problem? before installed vuex it is working properly

Comment: You describe a problem that doesn't exist in general. This command shouldn't break anything. Nothing specific can be suggested. That there's a problem suggests that there are problems with dependencies that existed previously. Try to reinstall node modules (delete the folder and npm install), if this doesn't help then try to revert package json and lock file to the state before vuex (both should always be under git control) and repeat the reinstallation, if this doesn't help then backup and remove lock file and repeat. Make sure dev server doesn't run when you do this